# Sort dataframe into desired format using pivoting

Tags: r, dplyr

I currently have a data frame with this format:

```
week    A_Revenue   B_Revenue   C_Revenue   D_Revenue   A_P_pct.chg B_P_pct.chg C_P_pct.chg D_P_pct.chg
34  8465.9  12299.98    10621   1548.375    59.50223    34.06917    41.46715    -3.305127
33  5307.7  9174.35 7507.75 1601.3  NA  NA  NA  NA
```

And I would like to format it the following way:
[image]

How can I go about it? I tried tidyr::pivot_longer(2:5) which gives me the Revenue Source as a stand alone column but couldn't get the weekly revenues into their respective columns.

Edit:
The full data set contains daily transactions to which I add:

```
dat$week <- format(dat$Date, format = "%V")
```

to include the week range for those days. Then I filter the desired weeks with the following code:

```
dat1 <- dat %>%
  filter(between(week, todays_week - 2, todays_week - 1)) %>%
  group_by(week) %>%
  summarise(A_Revenue = sum(A_Revenue),
            B_Revenue = sum(B_Revenue),
            C_Revenue = sum(C_Revenue),
            D_Revenue = sum(D_Revenue)) %>%
  mutate(A_P_pct.chg = 100 * ((A_Revenue - lag(A_Revenue))/lag(A_Revenue)),
         B_P_pct.chg = 100 * ((B_Revenue - lag(B_Revenue))/lag(B_Revenue)),
         C_P_pct.chg = 100 * ((C_Revenue - lag(C_Revenue))/lag(C_Revenue)),
         D_P_pct.chg = 100 * ((D_Revenue - lag(D_Revenue))/lag(D_Revenue)))
```

This yields the initial data frame posted which I am attempting to reshape into the image provided for easy comparison.

Comment: Don't you still need a `week` column in the reformatted data?

Comment: I don't think so, those values are separated by column in the expected output unless that doesn't seem clear

Comment: Do you only have two rows in your actual data? I thought it was just a sample. I'll add the answer I just created anyway and you can tell me where I've misunderstood.

Comment: Ill edit the question to include my process

Comment: @pseudospin https://ufile.io/phqf37kh here is the full data structure for this past month

Comment: I think you might need a tidyverse expert to do the last step in that chain. I'm just far too tempted to redo the whole thing from scratch - i.e. make it a long form table with the revenue streams in separate rows right at the start.

Comment: As in have a column for Revenue and the rest weeks?

Comment: I am pretty much a novice at this so I am not sure if my approach is even the best, just made sense in my head lol

Comment: What you are doing is fine, it just needs something a bit intricate to shuffle the data around in the last step (and I don't really know how its done with the piping tidyverse stuff)

Comment: Thanks for the brainstorm, I've been messing with it all day and still haven't gotten around to it :'/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of calculating for each column differently you can get the data in long format and calculate  `sum` and `pct.change` for each `name`.

```
library(dplyr)

todays_week = lubridate::week(Sys.Date())

dat %>%
  filter(between(week, todays_week - 2, todays_week - 1)) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = ends_with('Revenue')) %>%
  group_by(name, week) %>%
  summarise(value = sum(value, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  mutate(rev_prev_week = lag(value),
         pct_change = (value - rev_prev_week)/rev_prev_week * 100)
```

Comment:    That is just what I was trying to do, do you have any reading recommendations in regards to all the tricks you know with dplyr?

Comment: One last question, if I want to add a mutate case_when to describe the performance of the week.  Do I need the add the higher value first in all cases or is there a way to evaluate the same row if another parameter applies?

Comment: `case_when` checks for the condition in the same order as it is written. Since `value >= 1000` is `TRUE` for all of them it returns "Under" for all. You should start with higher value first and slowly decreasing it from there.

Comment: Makes sense, that was I was thinking if two of the values are the same can I have the name be X or Y to reduce the amount of lines? I tried name == "A_Revenue" | "B_Revenue" & value >= 1000 ~ "Under" but got an error

Comment: You can write it like :  `name %in% c("A_Revenue","B_Revenue") & value >= 1000 ~ "Under`.